# Implementing custom audio filters that work on file-backed Audio[] objects

Tags: sound

[`Audio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Audio.html) supports out-of-core processing.  We can create a file-backed Audio object using `au = Audio[File[...]]`.  Any filters applied to it will create a new file-backed Audio, and processing will happen without loading *all* the data into memory at the same time.

Is there a way to create our own audio filters that can act on file-backed Audio objects, either in pure Mathematica or in C/LibraryLink?  The typical filter would need access to an interval $[t-\Delta t, t+\Delta t]$ to be able to compute the amplitude at $t$ (similar to [`ImageFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFilter.html)).

---

Note: I sent the same question to Wolfram Support today, however, at this point I have little hope for a documented solution.  Audio is still very new, and I expect lots of improvements and additions in the future.  I am posting the question here on SE in the hope that there may exist a simple *undocumented* way that I haven't discovered yet.